# Taking raw images don't work

Tags: raspicam

I'm taking a photo with the following command:

```
raspiyuv -n -t 30 -awb off -ex verylong -drc off -ss 6000000 -ifx off -ISO 100 -o D-0-ISO100-t-ssmax.raw
```

It's clear to me, I'm taking a photo in RAW-format. But I can't open it with an program like darktable or alike.

In contrast, I take a photo with raspistill, and add the raw information the the jpeg file, I can extract the raw informations from the jpeg file and for example, get a DNG-File, darktable can open.
For the extraction, I'm using: https://github.com/illes/raspiraw

What do I do wrong?

Comment: raspiyuv doesn't output RAW (i.e. bayer) data; it outputs the fully post-processed but unencoded image (i.e. your file will contain white-balanced, exposure-corrected 8-bit YUV 4:2:0 planar data, not the unprocessed 10-bit bayer data from the camera's sensor). The only way to obtain the bayer data is currently by extracting it from JPEG metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw data can be extracted from the jpeg files using.

https://github.com/illes/raspiraw

It returns a DNG-file.